# Getting all VM hostnames

Tags: python, vsphere

I need to obtain a list of all the hostnames of all the VM's that reside on two ESXI servers using pysphere. I have attempted using the basic methods, but am unable to get a hostname in my testing using:

```
from pysphere import VIServer
server = VIServer()
server.connect("192.168.0.19", "user-name", "password")
vmlist = server.get_registered_vms()
vm1 = server.get_vm_by_path(
    "[datastore1] Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit .160/Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit    .160.vmx")
vm1.get_property('hostname')
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of ntpath and os modules like this

```
import os
import ntpath
for i in vmlist:
    print os.path.splitext(ntpath.basename(i))[0]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but its not a problem with the output but rather pulling the hostname from the VM using pysphere

Comment: skip the two last lines in your code. and go through the loop with your vmlist and you get all the hostnames.

Comment: that worked but it prints name of the VM not the actual hostname of the OS. For example I have a VM named "CentOS 6.4 32-bit .93" but the actual hostname under /etc/hostname is "dev-box"

Comment: aahhh it won't work :). there is no straightforward approach that I know for this then. you should remember that what's "inside" is usually pretty separated from the vmware host machine.So you have to actually treat them just like normal servers.

Comment: let me try an idea and I will update you in a few hours (I am at work now).
1-ssh to the vmware host
2-mass ping the range of the ips you are using.(to populate the arp table)
3-use pysphere to get the mac addresses of the vms.
4-get the arp table witrh: excli network ip neighbor list
5- parse the table, compare mac address from the vms. get ip addresses.
6-ssh to the addresses, and get the hostname.
you have to write all that in python, it's going to take you a while. or else I hope someone else knows a better idea/api/lib that can help you.